# I want to make an auto upgradable calendar like the Facebook calendar to add to my Google calendar

Tags: facebook, calendar

My goal is simple: I want to make a calendar that takes information from my account with my local library (book name and due date) and add it to my Google calendar but I want it so that whenever my account is updated (I borrow a new book) the information is also updated on the calendar. The only thing is that I have zero clue where to begin, and what languages to use, and what to do exactly. If anyone can lay out the steps for me with some detail I will be really grateful. Also, I'm not sure whether this qualifies as a programming question since I'm asking what to do rather than how to do it, so treat it as is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to accomplish your task using means Google already provides instead of writing a local script which would probably require more of maintaining and synchronization among devices.
The one possible approach would be to synchronize your local folder with Google drive and write a google script which would update your calendar based on Google Drive changes.
The example of the script which tracks modification dates of files in one's drive is here: https://ctrlq.org/code/19921-monitor-drive-files-google-script

Comment: Apologies for the lateness but I don't think you got my question. My physical library has a website and I want to take information from there and put it into a webcal then add that cal to Google. I was thinking of writing a script that fetches the info I need from the site and then makes seperate events for them on my calendar but that seems too complicated at my current level so I was looking for something easier. Thank you for your answer, though.

Comment: Yes, I understood you incorrectly and in your case my suggestion doesn't work at all. I thought you have a local library. I don't see any shortcuts for your task.